# how to create log files in sharepoint which holds track of my all updates i am doing within my code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Here is my code which is creating text, number, datetime and currency type column in my list-

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint ;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Bulk_Site_Update
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Createcalsite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(txtPWAUrl.Text))
    {
        oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
        {
            oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            foreach (SPWeb projsite in oSPWeb.Webs)
            {
                if (projsite.WebTemplate.ToString().ToLower() == "projectsite")
                {
                    if (projsite.Title == "proj2")
                    {

                        SPList lst = projsite.Lists[txtListName.Text];

                        if
                            (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Singleline")
                        {


                            if (!lst.Fields.ContainsField(txtColumnName.Text))
                            {
                                SPFieldText fldName = (SPFieldText)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                fldName.MaxLength = 200;
                                lst.Fields.Add(fldName);
                            }


                        }
                        if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Number")
                        {
                            if (!lst.Fields.ContainsField(txtColumnName.Text))
                            {
                                SPFieldNumber fldEmpID = (SPFieldNumber)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                SPFieldType.Number.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                fldEmpID.DisplayFormat = SPNumberFormatTypes.NoDecimal;
                                lst.Fields.Add(fldEmpID);
                            }
                        }
                        if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Date")
                        {
                            if (!lst.Fields.ContainsField(txtColumnName.Text))
                            {
                                SPFieldDateTime fldDob = (SPFieldDateTime)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                SPFieldType.DateTime.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                fldDob.DisplayFormat = SPDateTimeFieldFormatType.DateOnly;
                                lst.Fields.Add(fldDob);
                            }
                        }
                        if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Currency")
                        {
                            if (!lst.Fields.ContainsField(txtColumnName.Text))
                            {
                                SPFieldCurrency fldSal = (SPFieldCurrency)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                SPFieldType.Currency.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                fldSal.Currency = SPCurrencyFieldFormats.UnitedStates;
                                fldSal.DisplayFormat = SPNumberFormatTypes.TwoDecimals;

                                lst.Fields.Add(fldSal);
                            }
                        }

                SPView defaultView = lst.DefaultView;
                            defaultView.ViewFields.Add(txtColumnName.Text);
                            defaultView.Update();
                            lst.Update();

                    }
            }

                oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }

        oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }

}
    MessageBox.Show("Update Successfully");
}
```

So what I have to modify in this code to create log files.

Comment: If you can explain your code, i.e. at which point you to log activities, then it would easy for other readers to answer.

Comment: I think you also need to add how you want to log these and where.  @PaulStrupeikis provides the method for writing to event/ULS logs, but database or SharePoint list would be different if you are just tracking for change purposes.  As for your code - you can log output anywhere (it's your code).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the the following things:

1. Add a reference to `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation`
2. Create an instance of a `SharePointServiceLocator.GetCurrent().GetInstance<ILogger>()`

Code example:

```
ILogger logger = SharePointServiceLocator.GetCurrent().GetInstance<ILogger>();
logger.TraceToDeveloper(String.Format("Successfully added a column in the following list: {0}", lst.RootFolder.Url));
```

or

```
ILogger logger = SharePointServiceLocator.GetCurrent().GetInstance<ILogger>();
try
{    
  //[...]
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  logger.TraceToDeveloper(ex);
}
```

You can find more information here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798361.aspx